# Contact Form 7 - Mass Checkboxes displayed by line break separation within notification emails

Tags: email, checkbox, line-breaks, contact-form-7

I have a question about the checkbox value items that I receive in my mail after someone fills in my contact form 7.
If someone has checked these three boxes in the form:

- CHECKBOX1
- CHECKBOX2
- CHECKBOX3

Then in my mail they appear as:
CHECKBOX1, CHECKBOX2, CHECKBOX3

However, I would like to change the comma separation into line breaks.
Plus add a unique value for each checkbox so I can add in a URL:
Should be displayed in the email like this:

- CHECKBOX1 – URL LINK
- CHECKBOX2 – URL LINK
- CHECKBOX3 – URL LINK

I really need this, can somebody please tell me where I can change this within contact form 7’s code?

Or does someone know another way without using contact form 7?

Answer (score 0):

For HTML emails,

Edit: `wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/classes.php`

Look for `function mail_callback`. In my version it's at line 631.

Edit the function to be as so:

```
function mail_callback( $matches, $html = false ) {

  if ( isset( $this->posted_data[$matches[1]] ) ) {
    $submitted = $this->posted_data[$matches[1]];

    if ( $html ) {
      $replaced = strip_tags( $replaced );
      $replaced = wptexturize( $replaced );
    }

    if ( is_array( $submitted ) )
      $replaced = join( '<br/>', $submitted );
    else
      $replaced = $submitted;

    $replaced = apply_filters( 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced', $replaced, $submitted );

    return stripslashes( $replaced );

  }

  if ( $special = apply_filters( 'wpcf7_special_mail_tags', '', $matches[1] ) )
    return $special;

  return $matches[0];

}
```